# Does my vim not use the config in the home directory when used with sudo?

Tags: sudo, vim, vi, home

I tried to manipulate a file with sudo but NERDTree was obviously not loadable. I am new to vi(m) so I don't have many other plugins which I would have had the chance to see if vim missed to load them. But I could imagine that it would look for a config under `/root` instead of `/home/$MY_USERNAME` instead if used with `sudo`, could that be?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Running as root a program (Vim is already big) with a bunch of plugins is not a very cautious move. I suggest `sudo -e` or `sudoedit`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. Execution of something with `sudo` switches environment into root's. And yes, copy plugins to `/root/.vim` - can solve the problem permanently, although it is not a best solution.

To solve the problem, you can use vi's command `set runtimepath` and specify in your `sudo vi` where your user-level plugins are.

Look here for full documentation:
[http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'runtimepath'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27runtimepath%27)

And this extremely short tutorial also could be useful:
https://howchoo.com/vim/how-to-install-vim-plugins-without-a-plugin-manager#set-your-vim-runtimepath